# Como tratar uma exception de renderização no WPF (Windows Presentation Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exceção

Aleatoriamente meu sistema causa essa exception (que só vejo por conta dos logs deixados nos eventos do Windows). É uma aplicação que fica rodando 24h por dia todos os dias. Quando o erro ocorre, a tela congela e se eu clicar em qualquer coisa, o programa fecha com a mensagem de erro do Windows.

Já implementei um gerenciamento de memória com o GC porém aparentemente não é este o problema.

O ponto em questão é que eu não consigo encontrar onde está o problema, já que depurei todo o projeto, fiz testes unitários e tudo corre perfeitamente, além disso pelo meu entendimento, essas classes são da própria Framework .NET, mais especificamente da parte de renderização.

Todas as vezes que ocorre, embora seja difícil de ocorrer, é a mesma exception, e eu não sei como trata-la.

Como posso identificar a origem desse problema ou tratar essa exception? Se houvesse uma forma de apenas tratar a exception para que o aplicativo não travasse já ajudaria.

```
Aplicativo: StreamWpf.exe
Versão do Framework: v4.0.30319
Descrição: O processo foi terminado devido a uma exceção sem tratamento.
Informações da Exceção: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Pilha:
   em System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE+Channel.SyncFlush()
   em System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowSettings(Boolean, System.Nullable`1<ChannelSet>)
   em System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowPos(IntPtr)
   em System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   em System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   em MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   em MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   em System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   em MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   em MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   em MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   em MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   em MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   em MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   em MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   em MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   em MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   em MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   em MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   em System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   em System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   em System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   em StreamWpf.App.Main()

Nome do aplicativo com falha: StreamWpf.exe, versão: 2.0.0.0, carimbo de data/hora: 0x5981bd3b
Nome do módulo com falha: KERNELBASE.dll, versão: 6.2.9200.16864, carimbo de data/hora: 0x531d2c84
Código de exceção: 0xe0434352
Deslocamento da falha: 0x00011a65
ID do processo com falha: 0xf28
Hora de início do aplicativo com falha: 0x01d30d1967a85ab5
Caminho do aplicativo com falha: C:\Program Files\Stx\StreamWpf.exe
Caminho do módulo com falha: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
ID do Relatório: abd4667b-8273-11e7-afa6-0019b9fb11aa
Nome completo do pacote com falha: 
ID do aplicativo relativo ao pacote com falha:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala Renan, se eu te falar que passei o dia ontem com esse mesmo problema heheh.

Bom o que consegui foi utilizar isto:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
```

Na **MainWindow** da minha aplicação e ai sim ir tratando cada problema, veja se te ajuda.

Comment: Obrigato @Otto! Vou testar essa solução. Já estava começando a ficar desesperado.